# How can I determine which of Brainwave is dominant as one state by EEG data?

Tags: methodology, eeg, brain-waves

I am a student working on EEGs.

I have a EEG data of Brainwave in 4 emotional states, namely anger, sorrow, joy and pleasure. Is there any method for determining the difference between these emotional states by analyzing the 5 Brainwaves (gamma to delta)? And how can I detect which brainwaves are dominant?

Answer (score 1):

Each "brainwave" is a range of frequencies that make up the signal, usually called a frequency band (ie. "the gamma frequency band"). To determine differences between bands, you would generally look at the [power spectral density (PSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) of the signal. For instance, you may want to compare the average power in each frequency band.

In practice the PSD is estimated by calculating a [periodogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram).